# Cast after Join

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to add some information to an entity before returning it via GET.

I created a class, kind of like a ViewModel, with the original entity plus one int field, to return the complete data to a client, but was enable to make it work. I also don't want to return the Depth field, but need it in the `Where`.

How do I go from this `Join` to correctly returning the data to a client?

Is iterating and copying item by item the only way?

```
public class FluxoHierarchyOutput
{
    public FluxoHierarchy FluxoHierarchy { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<FluxoHierarchyOutput> GetFluxoHierarchyByFluxo([FromRoute] int idFluxo)
{
    return _context.FluxoHierarchy
        .Join(
            _context.FluxoClosure,
            h => h.NodeId,
            c => c.ChildId,
            (h, c) => new { FluxoHierarchy = h, c.ParentId, c.Depth }
        )
        .Where(x => x.FluxoHierarchy.FluxoId == idFluxo && x.Depth == 1)
        .ToList(); // Cannot implicitly convert type...
}
```

Comment: The presence of the word *Join* makes this question pure LINQ rather than EF (Core). In EF (Core) query one will use navigation properties rather than joins, thus the query will be much simple and won't have any problems.

Comment: @IvanStoev And how would this be done in the current scenario?

Comment: I can't say because you didn't show the relevant entity model, which is essential for EF related questions. The problem with joins (LINQ, SQL) is that they hide the cardinality of the relationship. Just from your query, it's unclear if this is one-to-one or one-to-many, who is the principal and dependent etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a `Select`, your query returns an anonymous object, which then will have to be converted to your actual return type. This conversion cannot be implicit as the error message is telling you. Add a `Select` to the end of your query and it will work.

```
return _context.FluxoHierarchy
    .Join(
        _context.FluxoClosure,
        h => h.NodeId,
        c => c.ChildId,
        (h, c) => new { FluxoHierarchy = h, c.ParentId, c.Depth }
    )
    .Where(x => x.FluxoHierarchy.FluxoId == idFluxo && x.Depth == 1)
    .Select(s => new FluxoHierarchyOutput {
        FluxoHierarchy = s.FluxoHierarchy,
        ParentId = s.ParentId,
        //Add all the fields you want.
    })
    .ToList();
```

You have the same issue in the `Join` as Robert Harvey explained.

Answer (score 3):

Try projecting to your concrete type, rather than an anonymous type.

```
        (h, c) => new FluxoHierarchyOutput { FluxoHierarchy = h, c.ParentId, c.Depth }
```

You're going to need a `Select` in there somewhere, probably just before the `ToList()` call.  Otherwise, your result will be the entire join.

Comment: That solved half the problem. The Depth field is used in the Where, but I don't want to return it to the client.

Comment: You can choose whatever you want to return in your `Select`.

Answer (score 3):

The fluent API is not the prettiest with joins. Here is the same thing using query syntax. You completely avoid having to specify an intermediate result prior to the select.

```
return (
   from h in _context.FluxoHierarchy
   join c in _context.FluxoClosure on h.NodeId equals c.ChildId
   where h.FluxoId == idFluxo && c.Depth == 1
   select new FluxoHierarchyOutput {
       FluxoHierarchy = h,
       ParentId = c.ParentId
   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Agreed. I was about to say the same thing, but though some crazy people will say it doesn't exactly answer the question.